# MySQL View Order By does not work in Select * FROM view WHERE

Tags: mysql, view

I am having issue with running a query on a view with where condition where the order by inside view does not work any more. I have tried my best to explain my situation with a simple example below.
Say, I have a table named `users` with 2 columns: `name` and `group`
and a view created with:
`CREATE VIEW view_name AS SELECT name, group FROM users order by name`
Now if I run a query `SELECT * FROM view_name WHERE group = 'somegroup'` I dont get the results ordered by `name`

Comment: Note that queries against views in MySQL cannot access underlying indexes, rendering their utility questionable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are using a materialized view, a view in MySQL in simply a query which executes on the underlying table.  And, in MySQL, tables are *not* ordered, so putting an `ORDER BY` clause into your view does not "order" the data there.  Instead, you should use an `ORDER BY` clause when you use the view:

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS
SELECT name, `group`
FROM users

SELECT *
FROM view_name
WHERE `group` = 'somegroup'
ORDER BY name;
```

Comment: This is a little confusing as when I run `select * from view_name` result shown is with `order by`

Comment: @AlwaysaLearner It MAY be sorted as specified in the view text, but not MUST be.

Comment: Thank you both... Though it was not the answer I was hoping for, now I know how to deal with the issue